# Reading .sav with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

So, I'm trying to read a .sav file using python and turn it into a .csv. I already got my code to read .sav files, and I also checked it with a test .sav, which I managed to turn into a csv. I then went on to use the real .sav file, and not it no longer works.
Here is the code:

```
import pyreadstat

df, meta = pyreadstat.read_sav('./RaceDatas.sav')

df.to_csv('BloodRace.csv', index=False)
```

Here is the error:

```
runfile('C:/Users/usuario/Desktop/Python tests/ARK Projects/no.py', wdir='C:/Users/usuario/Desktop/Python tests/ARK Projects')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "c:\users\usuario\desktop\python tests\ark projects\no.py", line 3, in <module>
    df, meta = pyreadstat.read_sav('./RaceDatas.sav')

  File "pyreadstat\pyreadstat.pyx", line 364, in pyreadstat.pyreadstat.read_sav

  File "pyreadstat\_readstat_parser.pyx", line 1099, in pyreadstat._readstat_parser.run_conversion

  File "pyreadstat\_readstat_parser.pyx", line 867, in pyreadstat._readstat_parser.run_readstat_parser

  File "pyreadstat\_readstat_parser.pyx", line 797, in pyreadstat._readstat_parser.check_exit_status

ReadstatError: Invalid file, or file has unsupported features
```

Does anyone know what can be the problem? I thought perhaps it was the way in which the .sav I'm trying out is structured in a weird way, but its structured like normal.

The .sav itself is 451 KB

I tried with a simple .sav file, and it worked like intended. I tried with the main code, and it didn't work.
I'm expecting it to at least turn the .sav into a python/pandas data frame to then turn into a .csv

Comment: Can you share an example of what your .sav file looks like?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Solution. I Hope it would help.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

# Set the working directory
os.chdir("C:/Users/Desktop/")

# Read the .sav file
df = pd.read_spss("file.sav")

# Print the dataframe
print(df)

# Write the .csv file
df.to_csv("file.csv")
```

Comment: I tried using this code, but it didn't work. Gave me the same error code.

Comment: Make sure that you correctly installed pyreadstat with `pip install pyreadstat`. If it does not help you may try another sav-file to exclude the possibility that it is a corrupt sav-file. In my case this worked.

Answer (score 0):

I found this...

> It is considered as data is in observation order, e.g. all variable
> values for the first observation, followed by all values for the
> second observation, etc. The format of the data record varies
> depending on the compression code in the file header record. The data
> portion of a .sav file can be uncompressed:
>
> ```
> code 0: compressed by bytecode
> ```

i would recommend using a context manager to read the file to avoid .sav file compression weirdness.

Also... below is a parameter for the pyreadstat.read_sav() method:

> encoding (str, optional) – Defaults to None. If set, the system will
> use the defined encoding instead of guessing it. It has to be an
> iconv-compatible name

your encoding options are ['ASCII', 'EBCDIC', 'utf-8']

```
with pyreadstat.read_sav('./RaceDatas.sav', encoding='utf-8') as savfile:
    savfile.to_csv('BloodRace.csv', index=False)
```

or

```
data = pyreadstat.read_sav('./RaceDatas.sav', encoding='ASCII')
df = data[0]
meta = data[1]
```

Comment: I tried using a context manager, and the code still didn't work. I can't try the second code you tried, as the error would directly come from the first line as the file isn't being read at all

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty much clear. The sav file is corrupted. There is no reason why it should work on one but not other.

Here is the parsing function: https://github.com/Roche/pyreadstat/blob/master/src/spss/readstat_sav_read.c#L1570

There are only two places where `READSTAT_ERROR_PARSE` is returned, so you may want to check that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
from scipy.io import readsav

import pandas as pd

sav_df = readsav('RaceDatas.sav')

df=pd.DataFrame(sav_df)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?